# Parse with DOMParser or innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, parsexml

What is the difference between these examples and why would you use one instead of another, for performance or browser compatibility? Is there something cannot be done between these two?

```js
txt="<address>"+
 "<street>Roble Ave</street>"+
  "<mtfcc>S1400</mtfcc>"+
  "<streetNumber>649</streetNumber>"+
  "<lat>37.45127</lat>"+
  "<lng>-122.18032</lng>"+
  "<distance>0.04</distance>"+
  "<postalcode>94025</postalcode>"+
  "<placename>Menlo Park</placename>"+
  "<adminCode2>081</adminCode2>"+
  "<adminName2>San Mateo</adminName2>"+
  "<adminCode1>CA</adminCode1>"+
  "<adminName1>California</adminName1>"+
  "<countryCode>US</countryCode>"+
 "</address>";
 
 var d = document.createElement('div')
 d.innerHTML = txt

console.log(d.getElementsByTagName("streetNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
console.log(d.getElementsByTagName("postalcode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

or

```js
txt = "<address>" +
  "<street>Roble Ave</street>" +
  "<mtfcc>S1400</mtfcc>" +
  "<streetNumber>649</streetNumber>" +
  "<lat>37.45127</lat>" +
  "<lng>-122.18032</lng>" +
  "<distance>0.04</distance>" +
  "<postalcode>94025</postalcode>" +
  "<placename>Menlo Park</placename>" +
  "<adminCode2>081</adminCode2>" +
  "<adminName2>San Mateo</adminName2>" +
  "<adminCode1>CA</adminCode1>" +
  "<adminName1>California</adminName1>" +
  "<countryCode>US</countryCode>" +
  "</address>";

if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
} else // Internet Explorer
{
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}


console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("streetNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("postalcode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ub4mL80s/

http://jsfiddle.net/nm9yd0xz/1/

Comment: Adding a reference to Mozilla's article about the innerHTML security considerations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations

Answer (score 3):

One potential problem is that assigning to the `innerHTML` of a newly created element can execute inline handlers inside the `txt`:

```js
const txt = `
 <address>
 <street>Roble Ave</street>
 ...
 </address>
 <img src="nosrc" onerror="alert('evil');">
 `;

const d = document.createElement('div')
d.innerHTML = txt

// navigate through d
```

If the `txt` can contain arbitrary data, this is a security risk. `DOMParser` is much safer, because it doesn't have this vulnerability.

Also note that you can greatly simplify your

```
d.getElementsByTagName("streetNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

to

```
d.querySelector('streetNumber').textContent
```

Also note that jQuery is not involved in any of this - this is only Javascript.